# How can I bundle MONGODB?

Tags: mongodb, bundle, browserify, monk

I'm try to bundle with browserify when I try

```
browserify index.js > main.js
```

I get this error

```
Error: Can't walk dependency graph: Cannot find module 'mongodb-client-encryption' from '/home/xlrnz/Documenti/simple-crud/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js'
    required by /home/xlrnz/Documenti/simple-crud/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/connect.js
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:116:35
    at processDirs (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:269:39)
    at isdir (/usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:276:32)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/resolve/lib/async.js:25:69
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:194:21)
```

I can't understand. This is index.js:

```js
const dotenv = require("dotenv").config();

const monk = require("monk");

const db = monk(
  `mongodb+srv://simple-crud-xlrnz:${process.env.MONGO_DB_KEY}@simple-crud.jrjfl.mongodb.net/simple-crud-DB?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
);
```

and this is package-json:

```json
{
  "name": "simple-crud",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "monk": "^7.3.3"
  }
}
```

I'm stuck here for about 2hours anyone can help?

Comment: You're trying to connect from the browser directly to a MongoDB? That's probably a Very Bad Idea™. If technically feasible at all…

Comment: It's just for learning purpose on local machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client encryption module being referenced in your error message requires spawning a process which cannot be done from the browser. I am not very familiar with browserification but if you can configure it to ignore this module you might succeed with browserifying.

With that said, as pointed out in the comments, *generally* nobody would connect directly to a  MongoDB server from the browser. The closest sensible alternative is MongoDB Realm/Stitch. So the thing you are trying to do is basically not supported.

There are many MongoDB tutorials out there, I suggest following one of them.